# R: Multiple conditions to categorise two survey questions (factors) into one factor with levels None/Mild/Severe

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I have two factors X and Y with 5 levels (5 point Likert scale)

```
"[1] Never"      "[2] Rarely"     "[3] Sometimes"  "[4] Often"      "[5] Very Often"
```

Depending on both answers, I want to create a new factor Z with the following coding:

None: X = Never AND Y = Never

Mild: X = Rarely, Sometimes, Often, or Very Often AND Y = Never

Severe: Y = Rarely, Sometimes, Often, or Very Often

I tried many different multiple conditions but none worked.

Here is one of them:

```
Z <- c("None", "Mild", "Severe")
    factor(Z)
    levels(Z) <- c("None", "Mild", "Severe")
    if (!is.na((X == 1) && (Y == 1))) {
      Z == "None"
      } else if (!is.na((X != 1) && (Y == 1))) {
        Z == "Mild"
        } else (!is.na((X != 1) && (Y != 1))) {
          Z == "Severe"
          }
```

The error message is:

```
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"    Z== "Mild"
    } else (!is.na((X != 1) && (Y != 1))) {"
>       Z == "Severe"
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
>       }
Error: unexpected '}' in "      }"
>
```

The sample consists of about 4000 people and I want to know which participant is in which category (e.g. depression) according to his or her ratings on questions X and Y.

I am still an R beginner so I am grateful for your help!

All best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this sufficient?
You can use the three logical vectors to subset your data.

If you want more details it would help to have some of your data to work with. ([help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))

```
lev <- c("Never", "Never", "Never", "Rarely", "Sometimes", "Often", "Very Often")

set.seed(1)

X <- factor(sample(c(lev, "Never"), 15, replace=TRUE), levels=unique(lev))
Y <- factor(sample(lev, 15, replace=TRUE), levels=unique(lev))

None <-   X %in% c("Never") & 
          Y %in% c("Never")

Mild <-   X %in% c("Rarely", "Sometimes", "Often", "Very Often") &
          Y %in% c("Never")

Severe <- Y %in% c("Rarely", "Sometimes", "Often", "Very Often")
```

If you want to combine the logical vectors into a single factor vector it can be done something like this:

```
Z0 <- rbind(None, Mild, Severe)
z <- which(Z0, arr.ind=TRUE)
Z <- factor(rownames(z), levels=rownames(Z0))

data.frame(X, Y, Z)
#             X          Y      Z
# 1       Never     Rarely Severe
# 2       Never      Often Severe
# 3   Sometimes Very Often Severe
# 4       Never      Never   None
# 5       Never      Often Severe
# 6       Never Very Often Severe
# 7       Never      Never   None
# 8       Often  Sometimes Severe
# 9       Often      Never   Mild
# 10      Never      Never   None
# 11      Never      Never   None
# 12      Never      Never   None
# 13      Often      Never   Mild
# 14     Rarely Very Often Severe
# 15 Very Often      Never   Mild
```

Comment: Thank you so much Aksel for your help; it works!

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share the data.

Comment: @Andreas: No problem if you don't want to share the exact data. The idea is more to have example data that shares relevant characteristics with the original data. In the help link I posted above there is an answer concerning 'anonymization' of private data. It might be worth a read.